# How to prevent Kaggle re-downloading model files each time session is ended and restarted?

Tags: kaggle

I want to keep downloaded model data in a kaggle notebook

Here example kaggle notebook of mine : https://www.kaggle.com/furkangozukara/tglobal-xl-booksum-wip3r3

Whenever session is ended and restarted, it redownloads all of the model data from huggingface

For example the below image displays the model data download from the imported repository : https://huggingface.co/pszemraj/long-t5-tglobal-large-pubmed-3k-booksum-16384-WIP/tree/main

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the setting you've been looking for. Under `Notebook Options`, there's a setting labelled `PERSISTENCE`. You can select `Variable and Files` from the drop down menu to get persistent storage for both your variables and files.[image: Session Persistence in Kaggle]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/kaggle/working` directory, which is a persistent storage location in Kaggle's environment. Save your model files there, and they will persist across sessions.

Save:

```
model = # download from huggingface the 1st time #
tokenizer = # download from huggingface the 1st time #
...
import os, shutil
model_path = os.path.join('/kaggle/working', "YOUR_MODEL_NAME")
if os.path.exists(model_path): shutil.rmtree(model_path)
os.mkdir(model_path)
model.save_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_path)
```

Usage:

```
AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretraiend(model_path)
AutoTokenizer.from_pretraiend(model_path)
```

Comment: No it doesn't do that unless you check he setting labeled PERSISTENCE in Notebook Options and select "Files Only" or "Variables and Files". I tried saving to /kaggle/working and lost all my saved models.